# number format exception in Integer.parseInt("565a3eea61", 16));

Tags: java

Here I am trying to convert hexadecimal string to decimal but I am getting number formate exception could any one plz help me out to solve this problem.

```
Integer.parseInt("565a3eea61", 16));
```

Comment: The number is way over the limit of int type.

Comment: Have you checked ,when number format exception comes ?? Why don't you check docs once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is too big for an Integer. Try using `Long.parseLong()`

Answer (score 1):

To convert a hex string to a long, you could simply use `Long.parseLong(str, 16)`

OR, you can also use `BigInteger` class to handle such large numbers

Answer (score 0):

The number is too big for an Integer, and if you might use a value that is arbitrarily big I suggest using an appropriate type like

```
new BigInteger("565a3eea61", 16);
```